# delete key doesn't remove selected files

Tags: keyboard, xfce, debian

In file manager or on the desktop when I select a file and hit delete key it does nothing. Shift+delete works fine, as well as deleting in text editors. I'm using Debian Wheezy 7.4 with xfce desktop and nautilus 3.4.2 as the file manager.

Comment: Which file manager are you using? Thunar?

Comment: no, Nautilus 3.4.2

Comment: I think this is just one more example of Gnome devs thinking they know what you like. They seem to have removed this functionality and, of course, offer no way to modify it. May I recommend you switch to another file manager? Try nemo or thunar both of which do what you want.